# Am I clearing the query cache correctly?

Tags: mysql, optimization, cache, query-cache

I'm trying to optimize a query but need to make sure the query cache is cleared properly for obvious reasons, however it doesn't seem to be working.

I ran a query the first time and it took about **3.5** seconds and all additional times it took approx **0.25** seconds; however I made some changes to it and now want to test it again without relying on the cache.

I ran:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

...and then reran the query, but it doesn't seem to have had *much* affect as the execution times I am getting on the *first* run are approx **0.35** seconds and once again approx **0.25** seconds on any additional runs.

Is there another way to do this or do you think the first ever run was an outlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bypass the query cache you need to change your `SELECT` to [`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-in-select.html).

This will allow you to properly benchmark your query performance.

Be aware, that this does NOT affect the [InnoDB buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html). Whether or not the pool is populated will also affect performance.

A good rule of thumb is to run one query (with `SQL_NO_CACHE`), discard the result, and then run the query 3 more times to get a good idea of how fast the query is with the buffer pool populated.

Comment: It is an older codebase and is using MyISAM; is there anything extra I need to be concerned about with that like with InnoDB?

Comment: @Brett Unfortunately I don't have experience with MyISAM. However, looking at the documentation, it appears it has a cache similar to InnoDB, at least in terms of the net effect on performance: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/buffering-caching.html

Comment: Only once more should suffice.  MyISAM works the same -- but uses the  'key_buffer' and the OS's free space (instead of the buffer_pool).  Times like 0.001s indicate the Query Cache; 0.25s does not.  A ratio of about 10 (3.5/0.25=14) usually indicates cold vs warm cache (buffer_pool/key_buffer).